# custom hooks / state/ setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I am making a custom hooks to use in my navbar and other components
this:

```
export const useStickey = () => {
    const [menuFixed, setMenuFixed] = useState(false);
    const [overlayFixed, setOverlayFixed] = useState(false);
    const [ overlayRect, setOverlayRect] = useState(false);

    return {
        menuFixed,setMenuFixed,
        overlayFixed,setOverlayFixed,
        overlayRect,setOverlayRect,
        stickOverlay: useCallback(setOverlayFixed(true)),
        stickTopMenu: useCallback(setMenuFixed(true)),
        unStickOverlay: useCallback(setOverlayFixed(false)),
        unStickTopMenu: useCallback(setMenuFixed(false)),

    }
}
```

I don't know I'm on the right track about this part of the code but I have a problem finishing in a component I will use useEffect to get a ref and set my state:
overlayRect
but i don't know how i would do that on a custom hooks

without custom hooks I do it:

```
const inputRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  const handleOverlayRef = (c) => {
    if (!overlayRect) {
      setOverlayRect({ overlayRect: _.pick(inputRef.current.getBoundingClientRect(), 'height', 'width') })
    }
  }

  handleOverlayRef();
}, []);

<div ref={inputRef} style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayStyle : overlayStyle}>
            <Menu
              icon='labeled'
              style={overlayFixed ? fixedOverlayMenuStyle : overlayMenuStyle}
              vertical
            >
              <Menu.Item>
                <Icon name='twitter' />
                Twitter
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item>
                <Icon name='facebook' />
                Share
              </Menu.Item>

              <Menu.Item>
                <Icon name='mail' />
                Email
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
          </div>
```